# javascript how to use browse button to load audio files in html5 audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I am building a music player. I have it right now where their is a browse button that will load files into an array and then I am using the html5 audio to play the files. I added an onend event so it knows to increase the arraycount and loop through the playlist.

The problem is the files have to be in the same folder as the music player.html file for it to work. I got some code for a text editor that can read the files from any folder on the computer and I need some help to get the music player to do this( i am not going to show all the code because it is very long, just the parts that are important.

here is the music player code right now

html part

```
 <audio id="audio_2" controls preload> 

    <source src="ding.wav">

    </audio>

<input type="file" id="basicUploadFile" multiple="multiple">
```

javascript part

```
document.getElementById('audio_2').addEventListener('ended', function(){ 

if(document.getElementById('default').checked) {   





    songlist += 1;



    // check if we are at the end of the array



if(songlist == amountofsongs) {

songlist = 0;

}



    updatelabelsfunction();



// check for volume



if (volumetext == 1) {

this.volume = parseFloat(volumesforsongs[songlist] / 100);

}



    this.src = songs[songlist];

    this.play();







// if they choose random every time do the shuffle here     









}
```

here is the text editor code I found. I tried to put it in the music player but it does not play the files.

```
var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
alert(fileToLoad);

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
```

so the question is how can I get the music player to load files from any folder not just the folder the html file is in?

thanks